# Seeing `permission: denied` errors in task when upgrading to version 3 of concourse

Tags: concourse

We just upgraded one of concourses to 3.3.0 and we're getting a weird error on one of our jobs.

`runc create: exit status 1: container_linux.go:264: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:56: mounting \\\"/var/vcap/data/baggageclaim/volumes/live/17c7c6fb-a294-4274-4d3c-99d14980ab4f/volume\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/vcap/data/garden/graph/aufs/mnt/9985cede6b6b24ac198ea4a6b252fcaa56eb1f0062cf102e9d45f293ec82ee9d\\\" at \\\"/var/vcap/data/garden/graph/aufs/mnt/9985cede6b6b24ac198ea4a6b252fcaa56eb1f0062cf102e9d45f293ec82ee9d/scratch\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/vcap/data/garden/graph/aufs/mnt/9985cede6b6b24ac198ea4a6b252fcaa56eb1f0062cf102e9d45f293ec82ee9d/scratch: permission denied\\\"\""`

The configuration for the task is

```
- task: create-release
  config:
    platform: linux
    run:
      path: echo
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.0 of concourse and above, you must specify an `image_resource` in every task configuration.

Not having an `image` (now deprecated and renamed `rootfs_uri`) or `image_resource` defined in your task configuration used to be undocumented and unspecified behavior where it would let [Garden](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden-runc-release) choose the image based on Garden's default.

Try a task that looks like

```
- task: create-release
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: docker-image
      source:
        repository: alpine
    run:
      path: echo
```